# Why i can not stop setinterval by window.clearInterval?

Tags: javascript

This is my code for `window.setInterval` and `window.clearInterval`.

`window.setInterval` are work good, but when i tried to call `window.clearInterval` it's will show error `intervalId is not defined`

How can i do ?

.....................................................

```
<div onclick="start_setinterval('1')">START</div>
<div onclick="start_setinterval('0')">STOP</div>


<script>
  function start_setinterval(status) {
    var xxx = setInterval(function() {
      if (status == 1) {
        do_start_setinterval();
      } else {
        clearInterval(xxx);
      }
    }, 5000);
  }

function do_start_setinterval() {
  alert("test");
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Your `intervalId` is local-scoped and isn't persistent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

The `intervalId` variable you are using to store a reference to the setInterval is limited in its scope to the function `start_setinterval`. You might need to assign it to `window.intervalId` as a quick way of fixing this code.